# Numerical computation of a double integral

Tags: numerical-integration

I wish to numerically evaluate a function of the form

$$ P(v_0) = \frac{e^{\int_0^{v_0}F(v)dv}}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\int_0^{v_1}F(v)dv}dv_1} $$

In the denominator is the normalization constant which gives me the trouble.

The function $F$ is given by

$F(v) = -v+\frac{1}{1+\frac{v}{e^v-1}}-\frac{1}{1+\frac{ve^v}{e^v-1}}$

I can compute the nominator numerically:

```
P[v0_] := 
  Exp[NIntegrate[-v + 1/(1 + v/(-1 + E^v)) - 1/(
     1 + (E^v v)/(-1 + E^v)), {v, 0, v0}]];
Plot[P[v0], {v0, -20, 20}]
```

but can't manage to do it with the normalization constant included.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need for finesse or truncation here:

```
F[v_] = -v + 1/(1 + v/(E^v - 1)) - 1/(1 + (v E^v)/(E^v - 1));
G[v1_?NumericQ] := Exp[NIntegrate[F[v], {v, 0, v1}]]
Gnorm = NIntegrate[G[v1], {v1, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
(*    2.87582    *)
P[v0_?NumericQ] := G[v0]/Gnorm
```

Comment: Can you explain the importance of your use of `Set` here, as opposed to `SetDelayed`?

Comment: @CATrevillian `Set` (`=`) is for definitions that I want done only once, like defining `F[v]` or evaluating `Gnorm`, whereas `SetDelayed` (`:=`) is for definitions that I want done afresh at every call. I'd say that for defining `F[v]` we can do either `=` or `:=` ad libitum, but for `Gnorm` we absolutely must use an immediate `=` so that its numerical integral is evaluated only once, not afresh at every call.

Answer (score 9):

The function `F` decays so rapidly that it should be okay to truncate the domain of integration. For example, we have

```
NIntegrate[Q[v1], {v1, -30, 30}, PrecisionGoal -> 14]/ NIntegrate[Q[v1], {v1, -100, 100}, PrecisionGoal -> 14] - 1
```

> 2.66454*10^-15

So the following should have quite a few digits of precision:

```
F[v_] := -v + 1/(1 + v/(-1 + E^v)) - 1/(1 + (E^v v)/(-1 + E^v))
Q[v1_?NumericQ] := Exp[NIntegrate[F[v], {v, 0, v1}]];
const = NIntegrate[Q[v1], {v1, -30, 30}, PrecisionGoal -> 14]
P[v1_] := Q[v1]/const;
```

Answer (score -3):

isn't the normalization constant the integral starting at 0 (otherwise,
you need to find the function at -infinity where it blows up). So
use the final value of F as the normalization constant and divide
by it at the end.